# ¿Cómo podría hallar todas las combinaciones de la resta de un número sea igual a 0? Java (Backtracing)

Tags: java

Buenas estaba aprendiendo sobre backtracking. Aquí os dejo un ejemplo de mi problema: Si mi número es 3 las combinaciones serían 3-2-1=0, 3-1-2=0, 3-1-1-1=0. Serían **solo número naturales**
Y el programa que he elaborado para eso es el siguiente:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Main{
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.print(combinacionesResta(2));
    }
    
    //Calcula las primeras combinaciones de la resta de un numero 
    public static ArrayList combinacionesResta(int num){
        ArrayList<Integer> combinaciones = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        combinacionesResta(num, combinaciones, 0);
        return combinaciones;
    }
    
    private static void combinacionesResta(int num, ArrayList<Integer> combinaciones, int acumulado){
        if(num==acumulado){ //Condición de parada
            return;
        }else{
            //calculo todas las posibles combinaciones
            for(int i = 0; i<=num; i++){
                acumulado+=i; //Nos llevamos aqui el acumulado
                if(num-acumulado==0){
                    combinaciones.add(i);
                    combinacionesResta(num, combinaciones, acumulado);
                    combinaciones.remove(combinaciones.indexOf(i));
                }
                acumulado-=i; //Deshacemos 
            }
            
        }
    }
}
```

No se porque pero se me esta desbordando en la linea

```
combinacionesResta(num, combinaciones, acumulado);
```

Muchas gracias de antemano

Comment: eso incluye numeros negativos, complejos y/o irracionales?

Comment: No serían solo numeros naturales voy a escibirlo en la pregunta

Comment: eso incluye una cantidad infinita de combinaciones o esta limitado a cierta cantidad maxima de operandos?

Comment: Esta llamada combinacionesResta(num, combinaciones, acumulado); es siempre igual, en todas las vueltas, porque al entrar a la funcion nada cambia nunca!!!! la idea de backtracking, es que las cosas vayan cambiando, y no con una iteracion... por eso te da el error.. igual, no entiendo que tiene que hacer esta funcion...